# integrating Django 1.11 with a legacy database

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to read data from a legacy database with Django 1.11. I used inspectdb to save the database model to my app directory. But anytime I try to open Django shell or runserver I get this error

> ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Can anybody help me solve this error so I could read data from the database?

my models:

```
# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#   * Rearrange models' order
#   * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
#   * Make sure each ForeignKey has `on_delete` set to the desired behavior.
#   * Remove `managed = False` lines if you wish to allow Django to create, modify, and delete the table
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models  

class JustAccount(models.Model):        
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?  
    account_name = models.CharField(db_column='Account_name', max_length=100) # Field name made lowercase.  
    account_number = models.IntegerField(db_column='Account_number')  # Field name made lowercase.  
    ammount = models.FloatField(db_column='Ammount')  # Field name made lowercase.  

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'just_account'
```